# Идентификация пользователя на websocket-сервере

Tags: websocket

Возникла проблема идентификации пользователей, когда они подключаются с сайта к вебсокет-серверу (на Ratchet). Сайт закрытый, поэтому пользователи сайта точно авторизированы. Сессии хранятся в БД, потому нет возможности брать сессии из Memcached или Redis.
Как такое обычно решают?

Придумал несколько вариантов, но не уверен в каждом из них:

1. Передавать id пользователя сайта вебсокет-серверу при подключении. Но это легко можно подделать и нет гарантии что это этот пользователь.
2. Можно к первому варианту добавить связку с ip (На сайте в БД хранится последний ip, с которого заходил каждый юзер. Соответственно после подключения вебсокет-сервер проверит соответствие id с последним ip по БД). Но ip-адреса тоже могут повторяться. Например зашли с разных вкладок на одном устройстве.

Прошу помочь с подсказкой